# attach an programmatically generated pdf file to a node

Tags: 7, entities, files

Im using [PDF Using MPDF](https://www.drupal.org/project/pdf_using_mpdf) module to generate 4 files when a node is saved using its API function `pdf_using_mpdf_api`:

```
function MYMODULE_node_insert($node){
        // PDF generation :
        // Generate standard version
        $view = node_view($node, 'PDF');
        $html = drupal_render($view);
        pdf_using_mpdf_api($html, 'reference_'.$node->nid);

        // Generate short version
        $view = node_view($node, 'pdf_short');
        $html = drupal_render($view);
        pdf_using_mpdf_api($html, 'reference_'.$node->nid.'_short');

        // Generate Standard EN version
        $view = node_view($node, 'pdf_en');
        $html = drupal_render($view);
        pdf_using_mpdf_api($html, 'reference_'.$node->nid.'_en');

        // Generate short EN version
        $view = node_view($node, 'pdf_short_en');
        $html = drupal_render($view);
        pdf_using_mpdf_api($html, 'reference_'.$node->nid.'_short_en');
}
```

this code above generates 4 pdf files correctly and save them under `default/files/pdf_using_mpdf` directory.
users should be able to download these PDFs, so I added 4 fields in my content type for each PDF version (field_pdf1, field_pdf2, field_pdf3, field_pdf4).

I want to attach these stored files into their corresponding fields inside private directory (after success, i'll remove them from default/files/pdf_using_mpdf directory).

Before Im used to use `field_attach_update` to attach fields to a node, but for file fields how can I do this ?

What should be the value of the field : `$node->field_pdf1['und'][0]['value']` ? and how can I store them into private directory ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I didn't use [PDF Using MPDF](https://www.drupal.org/project/pdf_using_mpdf), so not sure what will be the file path for the PDFs got generated.

Anyway, these are general steps you need to perform for attaching files to a node.

- Create a file object representing our physical file
- Make it a managed file by calling `file_save()`
- Fill file field with file's properties and fill field's other properties like display and description
- Save the node to make attachment effective

You can utilize sample code below to get idea how to work on it.

```
<?php
// We have complete file path.
$file_path = '/whatever/path/to/file/sample.pdf';

$file = new stdClass;
$file->uid = $node->uid;
$file->filename = pathinfo($file_path, PATHINFO_BASENAME);
$file->uri = $file_path;
$file->filemime = file_get_mimetype($file_path);
// Make it permanent, otherwise it will get deleted later.
$file->status = FILE_STATUS_PERMANENT;

// Save file object to make it a 'managed file'.
file_save($file);

// We will save file under this location.
$destination = 'private://PDFs/';

// Make sure destination directory exists
//before moving files to that path.
// This will create directory if it does not exists.
file_prepare_directory($destination, FILE_CREATE_DIRECTORY);

// Now attach file to the file field.
$node->field_pdf[$node->language][0] = (array) $file;

// Default file type field comes with this extra properties.
$node->field_pdf[$node->language][0]['display'] = 1;
$node->field_pdf[$node->language][0]['description'] = 'Our special PDF';

// Save node to make the attachment effective.
node_save($node);
```

Apply correct file path and destination directory. Here is the post explaining it in detail: [Programmatically Attach Files to Node in Drupal 7](http://kb.detlus.com/articles/drupal/programmatically-attach-files-to-node-in-drupal-7/)

Comment: thanks your code helped me a lot, but I have I problem when I try to save more than one file at the same time, please check this new question if you can help me : http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/154930/attach-multiple-files-to-a-node-on-node-insert-and-move-them-to-private-director

Answer (score 1):

If I'm reading your question correctly, you'll need to

- Move the generated PDFs to your private dir
- Save them into Drupal's file system
- Attach them to the `$node->field_pdfX` fields

See this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7516912/2258752) on how utilize the Drupal File API to save a file and attached it to a node field. All you'll need to do is substitute out the `public://` prefix with `private://` and reference the correct paths & field names.

Comment: Im able to save a field and attach it to the node, but I have I problem when I try to save more than one file at the same time, please check this new question if you can help me : http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/154930/attach-multiple-files-to-a-node-on-node-insert-and-move-them-to-private-director

Answer (score 0):

I use [FPDF module](https://www.drupal.org/project/fpdf) library to generate a PDF file object,  this library is beautifull and very easy to learn, allows you to control perfect what your pdf will look, as you can see i use variable_get, set & delete, its because in library header and footer funtcions is hard to pass variables as parameters, i define them in a form, and set values on submit, here is last lines of code that does the magic:

```
$pdf->Close();
$nombre_paciente = variable_get('paciente').'.pdf';
$np = trim($nombre_paciente);
$np = str_replace(' ', '-', strtolower($np));

$data = $pdf->Output($np,'S');
$destination = 'public://users/files/'. $pdf_node->uid . '/'.  $pdf_node->nid . '/'. $idioma;
file_prepare_directory($destination, FILE_CREATE_DIRECTORY);
// what to do when the destination file already exists
$replace = FILE_EXISTS_REPLACE;
$my_file_obj = file_save_data($data, $destination .'/'. $np, $replace);
// above code saves file to server
// set node file field data
$pdf_node->field_resultado_pdf[$pdf_node->language][0] = (array) $my_file_obj;
$pdf_node->field_resultado_pdf[$pdf_node->language][0]['display'] = 1;
$pdf_node->field_resultado_pdf[$pdf_node->language][0]['description'] = 'Resultado';

node_save($pdf_node);

variable_del('idioma');
variable_del('paciente');
$pdf->Output('D', $np, true);
exit();
```

it calls twice pdf->Output(), one to save file and attached to node, second to display or download PDF file, this beheaivor depends on browers, chrome downloads the file, mozilla displays it in a new tab and downlods it.
My answer is based part in @Junaid answer.

[image]

```
$y = $pdf->GetY();
if($y > $page_brake){$pdf->AddPage('P', 'Letter');}
```