# Attach multiple files to a node on node_insert and move them to private directory

Tags: 7, files, nodes

I used the code below to save files and attach them to the node on node_insert, but the problem only the last file is saved and attached to the node :

```
function MYMODULE_node_insert($node){
        // PDFs generation :
        // Generate standard version
        $view = node_view($node, 'PDF');
        $html = drupal_render($view);
        pdf_using_mpdf_api($html, 'reference_'.$node->nid); // Function that generate the pdf
        $file_path = realpath('.').$GLOBALS['base_path'].'sites/default/files/pdf_using_mpdf/reference_'.$node->nid.'.pdf';
        // Attach pdf file to node
       MYMODULE_manage_pdf($node, 'field_reference_pdf', $file_path, 'Standard version of Reference PDF');

        // Generate short version
        $view = node_view($node, 'pdf_short');
        $html = drupal_render($view);
        pdf_using_mpdf_api($html, 'reference_'.$node->nid.'_short');
        $file_path = realpath('.').$GLOBALS['base_path'].'sites/default/files/pdf_using_mpdf/reference_'.$node->nid.'_short.pdf';
        // Attach pdf file to node
        MYMODULE_manage_pdf($node, 'field_reference_pdf_short', $file_path, 'Short version of Reference PDF');

        // Generate Standard EN version
        $view = node_view($node, 'pdf_en');
        $html = drupal_render($view);
        pdf_using_mpdf_api($html, 'reference_'.$node->nid.'_en');
        $file_path = realpath('.').$GLOBALS['base_path'].'sites/default/files/pdf_using_mpdf/reference_'.$node->nid.'_en.pdf';
        // Attach pdf file to node
        MYMODULE_manage_pdf($node, 'field_reference_pdf_en', $file_path, 'Standard English version of Reference PDF');

        // Generate short EN version
        $view = node_view($node, 'pdf_short_en');
        $html = drupal_render($view);
        pdf_using_mpdf_api($html, 'reference_'.$node->nid.'_short_en');
        $file_path = realpath('.').$GLOBALS['base_path'].'sites/default/files/pdf_using_mpdf/reference_'.$node->nid.'_short_en.pdf';
        // Attach pdf file to node
        MYMODULE_manage_pdf($node, 'field_reference_pdf_short_en', $file_path, 'Short English version of Reference PDF');

}
```

This is the helper function that was exceuted 4 times for each file field:

```
// Helper function for manage reference pdf files
function MYMODULE_manage_pdf($node, $field_name, $file_path, $description = 'Reference PDF'){
    $file = new stdClass;
    $file->uid = $node->uid;
    $file->filename = pathinfo($file_path, PATHINFO_BASENAME);
    $file->uri = $file_path;
    $file->filemime = file_get_mimetype($file_path);
    // Make it permanent, otherwise it will get deleted later.
    $file->status = FILE_STATUS_PERMANENT;

    // Save file object to make it a 'managed file'.
    file_save($file);

    $destination = 'private://reference_pdf';
    // Make sure destination directory exists
    //before moving files to that path.
    // This will create directory if it does not exists.
    file_prepare_directory($destination, FILE_CREATE_DIRECTORY);

    // We save the file to the private destinationy.
    $file = file_move($file, $destination);

    // Now update only PDF field
    $tmp_node = new stdClass();
    $tmp_node->nid = $node->nid;
    $tmp_node->type = 'reference';
    // Now attach file to the file field.
    $tmp_node->{$field_name}[LANGUAGE_NONE][0] = (array) $file;
    // Default file type field comes with this extra properties.
    $tmp_node->{$field_name}[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['display'] = 1;
    $tmp_node->{$field_name}[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['description'] = $description;
    field_attach_presave('node', $tmp_node);
    field_attach_update('node', $tmp_node);
    entity_get_controller('node')->resetCache(array($node->nid));

}
```

Only the last field is attached to the node (field_reference_pdf_short_en) and file also is moved to the private directory, and other fields still null!

**If I remove the line : `$file = file_move($file, $destination);` the 4 files are generated and attached to node**, but still inside public directory, and I need to move them to private directory.
what's wrong in this code ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am wondering why you call `field_attach_presave()`, `field_attach_update()` and `resetCache()`?

Comment: to only save the field without calling node_save()!